# How to find the highest char in list that is ranked in a specific order and includes letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example if I have the string '4K892' and I make it into a list with each character separate. How do I print the highest character using this order "23456789TJQKA"

pseudo code:

```
list = [4, K, 8, 9, 2]
Highestcharacter(list) = 'K'
```

Comment: What do you mean by highest character? The first one that comme from the left to right?

Comment: No, it's the highest based on the order in the question.

Comment: So according to your order, highest between `K` and `A` is A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the key parameter of the [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function, for example

**Slow version**:

```
order = '23456789TJQKA'
result = max('4K892', key=order.index)
print(result)
```

**Fast version**:

```
order = '23456789TJQKA'
lookup = {v : i for i, v in  enumerate(order)}
result = max('4K892', key=lookup.get)
print(result)
```

Note that *fast* and *slow* refers to the complexity of the functions, the *slow* version is `O(n*2)` and the *fast* version is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thx. The order line was exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a lookup dict:

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.ranking = {char: index for index, char in enumerate("23456789TJQKA")}
        self.hand = hand

    def sort(self):
        self.hand.sort(key=lambda x: self.ranking[x])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hand)

h = Hand(['4', 'K', '8', '9', '2'])
print(h) # ['4', 'K', '8', '9', '2']
h.sort()
print(h) # ['2', '4', '8', '9', 'K']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Presenting the algorithm behind the max(list, key) function**

You check every character from your pseudo list starting from the end of your orderd-list.Every time you make a match you keep in a 3rd array the result. They higher result is on the same cell as your pseudolist's higher character